# Pandas - Merge two dataframes with different number of rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following two dataframes:

df:

```
              value
period
2000-01-01    100
2000-04-01    200
2000-07-01    300
2000-10-01    400
2001-01-01    500
```

df1:

```
              value
period
2000-07-01    350
2000-10-01    450
2001-01-01    550
2001-04-01    600
2001-07-01    700
```

This is the desired output:

df:

```
              value
period
2000-01-01    100
2000-04-01    200
2000-07-01    350
2000-10-01    450
2001-01-01    550
2001-04-01    600
2001-07-01    700
```

I have `set_index(['period'])` on both df1 and df2. I also tried few things including concat and where statement after creating new column but notting works as expected. My first dataframe is primary. The second is kind of update. It should replace the corresponding values in the first one and in the same time add new records if any available.

How I can do this?

Comment: It looks like a simple concatenate. Can you elaborate on "nothing works as expected"?

Comment: This doesn't work: `pd.concat([df, df1], axis=0)`

Comment: @AlIvon Feel free to up vote the accepted answer and any others you found useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html), also if `dtype` of some index is `object` convert [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_datetime.html) which works nice if always `df1.index` is in `df.index`:

```
print (df.index.dtype)
object

print (df1.index.dtype)
object

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index)

df = df1.combine_first(df)
#if necessary int columns
#df = df1.combine_first(df).astype(int)
print (df)
            value
period           
2000-01-01  100.0
2000-04-01  200.0
2000-07-01  350.0
2000-10-01  450.0
2001-01-01  550.0
2001-04-01  600.0
2001-07-01  700.0
```

If not, then is necessary filter by [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) first:

```
df = df1.loc[df1.index.intersection(df.index)].combine_first(df)
```

---

Another solution with [`numpy.setdiff1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)

```
df = pd.concat([df.loc[np.setdiff1d(df.index, df1.index)], df1])
print (df)
            value
period           
2000-01-01    100
2000-04-01    200
2000-07-01    350
2000-10-01    450
2001-01-01    550
2001-04-01    600
2001-07-01    700
```

Comment: `combine_first` did the job. Thanks.

Comment: Glad can help you! Nice day!

Answer (score 3):

Is that what you want?

```
In [151]: pd.concat([df1, df.loc[df.index.difference(df1.index)]]).sort_index()
Out[151]:
            value
period
2000-01-01    100
2000-04-01    200
2000-07-01    350
2000-10-01    450
2001-01-01    550
2001-04-01    600
2001-07-01    700
```

PS make sure that both indices are of the same dtype - it's better to convert them to `datetime` dtype, using `pd.to_datetime()` method

Comment: `TypeError: unorderable types: datetime.date() > str()`. When removing `.sort_index()` the last result isn't coming. 2001-07-01 is missing.

Comment: @AlIvon, one of your indices has `object` dtype, hence this error

Answer (score 3):

Another option with `append` and `drop_duplicates`

```
d1 = df1.append(df)
d1[~d1.index.duplicated()]

            value
period           
2000-07-01    350
2000-10-01    450
2001-01-01    550
2001-04-01    600
2001-07-01    700
2000-01-01    100
2000-04-01    200
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the pd.concat() function to concatenate the data frames, then dropped the duplicates to get the results.

```
df_con = pd.concat([df, df1])
df_con.drop_duplicates(subset="period",keep="last",inplace=True)
print(df_con)

       period  value
0  2000-01-01    100
1  2000-04-01    200
0  2000-07-01    350
1  2000-10-01    450
2  2001-01-01    550
3  2001-04-01    600
4  2001-07-01    700
```

To set "period" back as an index just set the index,

```
print(df_con.set_index("period"))

            value
period           
2000-01-01    100
2000-04-01    200
2000-07-01    350
2000-10-01    450
2001-01-01    550
2001-04-01    600
2001-07-01    700
```